# Проверить, что приложение запущено

Tags: android

Запускаем приложение первый раз, потом оно свернулось... 
Теперь заново кликаем на значок и вот тут желательно проверить, что приложение уже запущено и не запускать заново, а просто сделать видимым свернувшееся?

Comment: Android всё делает за вас и именно так он и делает. Второй экземпляр  приложения не создается, а восстанавливается уже имеющийся из памяти

Comment: Если резко повращать сотик, то приложение вылетает и потом не заходит, что с ним происходит?

Comment: У Вас утечка памяти. Или перегружен методы активити (слишком 'тяжелые'). Нужен хотя бы logcat и минимальный пример кода, где воспроизводиться проблема.

Comment: Решил проблему - не вылетает приложение

Answer (score 1):

Используем примерно такой код:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo rti;
    for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       rti=list.get(i);
       if(rti!=null) {
          ComponentName cn=rti.baseActivity;
          if(cn.getShortClassName().contains("MyActivity")) {
              //наше приложение в списке запущенных
          }
       }
    }
```

Требуется пермишен:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean inited = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle s)
{
    super.onCreate(s);
    if (!inited) {
        ....
        inited = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (!inited) ... //если не инициализировано, то инициализируем приложение
}
```

Comment: Эх молодо-зелено. Неправильно написано...